# Can the bottom of the top row be absolutely positioned without wrappers?

Tags: css, flexbox

Having a container with a background image and several blocks in it, I'm trying to achieve the layout below. That is, showing the blocks in rows, such that the bottom of the first row is aligned with a fixed `y` value. All columns on the same row should (appear to) have the same height regardless of their contents. This would be trivial to achieve by putting blocks `A` and `B` together in a wrapping element, but I'm curious if it can be done without, with just these elements:

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="A">
    <p>A1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="B">
    <p>B1</p>
    <p>B2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="C">
    <p>C1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="D">
    <p>D1</p>
    <p>D2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="E">
    <p>E1</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

So far I tried applying a `transform: translateY(-100%)` to `A` and `B`, but that leaves a gap between them and the following blocks. If I could somehow get `A`, `B` and `C` to end up on the same row while keeping their widths, I could then move `A` and `B` up that way, but it's fighting flexbox.

The solution doesn't have to be flexbox based, though I do hope for something not too hacky.

[image: Desired layout]

Answer (score 0):

Below is the CSS Grid Solution for it.
You might have to play around a bit with rows and columns as per your requirement.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   font-family: sans-serif;
   font-size: 20px;
   font-weight: bolder;
   color: #484848;
  }
  body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
  }

  div {
   min-height: 100px;
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  }

  p {
   margin: 0;
   text-align: center;
  }

  #A { 
   grid-area: areaA;
   background-color: cadetblue;
  }
  #B { 
   grid-area: areaB;
   background-color: darksalmon;
  }
  #C { 
   grid-area: areaC;
   background-color: beige;
  }
  #D { 
   grid-area: areaD;
   background-color: bisque;
  }
  #E { 
   grid-area: areaE;
   background-color: darkseagreen; 
  }

  /* Adjust the padding in acordance with the height of 'A' and 'y'  */
  #container {
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: 25% 25% 25% 25%;
   grid-template-rows: auto;
   grid-template-areas:
   "areaA areaB . ."
   "areaC areaC areaC areaC"
   "areaD areaD areaE areaE";
   grid-column-gap: 16px;
   grid-row-gap: 16px;
   padding-top: 100px; 
  }

  p {
   width: 100%;
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translate3d(0,-50%,0);
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="A">
    <p>A</p>
  </div>
  <div id="B">
    <p>B</p>
  </div>
  <div id="C">
    <p>C</p>
  </div>
  <div id="D">
    <p>D</p>
  </div>
  <div id="E">
    <p>E</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but browser support is so bad that it's not a realistic solution at this moment.